# How can I get health insurance to travel through Europe?

Tags: europe, health, insurance

I'm a Brazilian living in Germany and I need new health insurance for fifteen days of traveling trough Europe (Netherlands, UK, France and Italy).

What is the best option to choose?

Comment: Do you already have health insurance? There might be loopholes or special cases I don't know about but I thought that German residents are required to have health insurance. If you are insured through a regular German health insurance, you are already covered elsewhere in the EU and should have a [European Health Insurance Card](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=509&langId=en) printed on the back of your health insurance card.

Comment: Also, you might simply consider appropriate travel insurance (something like [that](http://www.adac.de/produkte/versicherungen/auslandskrankenschutzversicherung/auslandskrankenschutz/)). Make sure it covers rescue, hospitalization and repatriation as needed and if something really serious happened to you, you would get long-term treatment in Germany under your current health insurance.

Answer (score 2):

Call a travel agent in Germany and ask for a travel health insurance policy to cover you for that period. Be explicit where you plan to travel to.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what a floater policy is, perhaps with some references